# Cannot use object of type WP_Error as array display category

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

I'm trying to deduce a category for my custom WordPress post, but I get this error. How to fix  ?

```
$events= wp_get_post_terms(get_the_ID(), 'events', array("fields" => "all"));
<?php echo $events[0]->name ?>

add_action( 'init', 'cptui_register_my_cpts' );
function cptui_register_my_cpts() {
  $labels = array(
    "name" => __( 'Events', '' ),
    "singular_name" => __( 'event', '' ),
    );

  $args = array(
    // HERE
    "label" => __( 'Events', '' ),
    "labels" => $labels,
    "description" => "",
    "public" => true,
    "publicly_queryable" => true,
    "show_ui" => true,
    "show_in_rest" => false,
    "rest_base" => "",
    "has_archive" => false,
    "show_in_menu" => true,
    "exclude_from_search" => true,
    "capability_type" => "post",
    "map_meta_cap" => true,
    "hierarchical" => false,
    "rewrite" => array( "slug" => "events", "with_front" => false ),
    "query_var" => true,

    "supports" => array( "title", "editor", "thumbnail", "excerpt", "revisions" ),          );
  register_post_type( "events", $args );

// End of cptui_register_my_cpts()
}
```

Comment: You have not added 'taxonomies'          => array('topics', 'category' ),   in args array()

Answer (score 0):

`wp_get_post_terms()` will return a `WP_Error` object if the taxonomy can't be found. So `$events[0]` won't exist if that happens.

If you're getting this error it means that there's no *taxonomy* named `events` registered on your site. So you'll need to make sure that you've used the correct name for the taxonomy whose terms you want to list.

Comment: I am sure that such a taxonomy is registered with me

Comment: Not possible, or you wouldn't get this error. Can you share the code you've used to register the taxonomy?

Comment: I added code to the description of the question. Please help

Comment: You've registered `events` as a custom _post type_, not a taxonomy. Have you registered a taxonomy as well? What are you attempting to display with `wp_get_post_terms()`?

Comment: I want on page single-event.php to deduce the category to which the currently open post belongs

Comment: You code doesn't register a taxonomy for events, or support the category taxonomy, so how are you categorising events?

Comment: section Events appeared in my admin panel, I go in there and add a record there and in the same place choose which category it will belong to, and then save

Comment: Are those categories shared by Posts? Like if you go to Posts > Categories, are the same categories listed there? Is there an Events > Categories page in your admin sidebar?

Comment: Yes, there is this section in the sidebar

Comment: thanks for the help. I registered a taxonomy and categories began to appear